# How to make an existing website(with a huge user base) as an openID provider?

Tags: openid, provider

I would like to make an existing website which is having a huge user base as an [openID](http://openid.net) provider. Though I find tons of articles regarding this subject, I could see all the articles talk about pointing to an **existing** openID provider server like Verisign, openID, etc. But I looking for these,

1. Setting up **own openID server**
2. How to enable an existing website to be an openID provider?
3. How the existing users of the website to give their existing id to act as an openID?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The OpenID protocol is located [here.](http://openid.net/developers/)  There are a few important details you need to iron out before you go crazy.  In order of importance:

1. Authentication scheme: how do you plan to protect your users from man-in-the-middle attacks.  OpenID does not specify this detail, but may provide some recommendations and ideas. The user is bounced from another site to yours, so you need to provide reasonable insurance that the site they got to is really yours.
2. Privacy policy: how do you plan to let the users control what account meta-data will be shared with other sites.  If you share everything, several users will be upset.  If you share nothing, you will inconvenience them.  Check out the MyOpenID provider for ideas on how to manage this.
3. Unique restful URLs that are controlled by your users.  For example, `http://username.mysite.com`.  The user needs to be able to control what gets displayed at that URL if it is not them.

If you can't provide these, you shouldn't do openid.  NOTE: on the [Developers page](http://openid.net/developers/), there are a series of technical documents that cover different aspects of the protocol--some of them are optional:

- OpenID Authentication
- Simple Registration
- Attribute Exchange
- Provider Authentication Policy Extention

That would be the first place to go for help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this [resource](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/)

When I implemented openID on a PHP site, this [link](http://code.google.com/p/partuza/source/browse/trunk/Application/Controllers/openid/openid.php?r=234) was very helpful:

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I am looking for a Java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

See the page titled "[Become an OpenID Provider](http://openid.net/add-openid/become-a-provider/)" at the OpenID Foundation website. It provides [software libaries](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/) for developers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what language your site is coded in so the best place to start would be to look at the existing libraries that allow you to run an identity server [openid libraries](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/).  If you're using a php framework then most have their own module (zend, symfony for example).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for JAva implementation